# Evaluating the significance of individuals parts of a combined score using a linear regression

Tags: regression, interaction

**Background**

We are studying peoples inflammation in response to having a certain medical condition. We have a group ~300 of patients, of which about half of these have this condition. We have seen that inflammation is higher in individuals with this condition, which we evaluated using a linear model with this R formula:

`Inflammation~Age+Sex+Condition` [formula1]

However, we were further curious if the relationship between having this condition and inflammation was different for men and women. To do that, we added an interaction term for condition and sex, like so:

`Inflammation~Age+Sex+Condition+Condition:Sex` [formula2]

This indeed proved to be the case, with men showing a stronger increase in inflammation than women in the group having the condition vs those not having it.

**Question**

The condition I mentioned is actually scored based on 5 separate parameters, and if someone is positive for 3 or more of these 5 parameters, this person is said to have the condition.
What we now want to evaluate is if one or more of these parameters is the driving force behind the difference between the sexes, i.e. a limited number of these parameters is causing men to show a stronger increase in inflammation. Or if it is really the combinations of parameters.
However, I was wondering what the best way was to go about this.

**My thoughts**

I can of course run the same model [2] that we used for the condition separately, 5 times for each of the 5 parameters, e.g. for parameter 1:
Inflammation~Age+Sex+Parameter1+Parameter1:Sex
However, I feel like there is probably a better approach.

I also though of running a model with interaction terms for all parameters at once, but this could pose some problems: The 5 parameters show correlations to each-other. This means that for a lot of R models, the common variance between these is not considered in calculating the significance of any these terms, in other words all terms in the formula are corrected for all other terms in the formula. Additionally, we would be using a large number of terms in the formula.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure, but a structural equation modelling (SEM) approach might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks mkt for taking the time! I'll have to read a bit into that collection of methods to see how they could be used. If I learn anything I'll post it here.